# Combobox doesn't show the new entries

Tags: .net, winforms, binding, entity-framework-4

Hi
I've problem in using entity framework + binding source + combobox .
I'm binding an entity to the binding source which is the data source of the combobox control, the problem appears when i add new item to the context like this :

```
myEntity ent =new myEntity() { entName="aaaa" };

ctx.AddObject('myEntitySetName',myEntity);

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

The combobox doesn't show the new entry...how can i refresh the data source of this control ?
I tried this :

```
myComboBox.DataSource = myBindingSource.DataSource;
```

It works fine for the first add operation and show the new entry but when i add second and third ...etc .. nothing happend .. the data is saved to the database correctly but it never listed in the combobox ...

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `BindingList` as the datasource to your `BindingSource`.

Then simply use the methods on the `BindingList` to add,remove, insert, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @leppie, this was great.
I don't know if this is right but i used BindonList class like this :

```
BindingList<myEntity> bl = bl = new BindingList<myEntity>(ctx.myEntitySet.ToList<myEntity>());

myBindingSource.DataSource = bl;
```

The save button code become like this :

```
myEntity ent = new myEntity() { name = textBox1.Text };

ctx.AddObject("myEntitySet", ent);  

bl.Add(ent);

ctx.SaveChanges();
```

If this is right it'll be super great if it's not it'll be good enough but i need to know if this is the right way to do it